# Certain objects are appearing larger and another has appeared post render

Tags: rendering

I'm relatively novice to Blender so I've struggled searching for a solution to the problem.

Certain objects, including the plane that the scene is on, have scaled up after rendering and a breadboard has appeared out of nowhere. I've looked through my scene collection and there are no unchecked eyeballs or cameras (which was a solution to other people's randomly appearing objects).

This is what the scene looks like;
[image]

and this is what it looks like rendered;
[image]

I'm not sure if there's any setting I should be including in this post.

Apologies if this is a dumb mistake and an easy fix, thank you in advance for any support.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? (remove all the useless objects)

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thank you for offering your support. Below is the linked file. I've removed everything bar wires and resistors. I've set the camera up and scaled up the light blue wire as an example of the render not reflecting the 3D viewport scene. 

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/10s0yegk7m4n6l7qxlgp4/circuit.blend?rlkey=o1jq9snia76r1gbaaal4cwe8m&dl=0

Comment: I can't see any difference in size, see a comparison between preview and render: https://zupimages.net/up/23/48/833k.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the objects appearing larger, I think you may just be zoomed in a bit in the Render window. Try to press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to see the whole render.

The hidden object that shows up in the render is most likely the *disabled* object called **HP**, since its name in the Outliner is gray. This is done using a third button that is hidden by default. To show it, open the *Restriction Toggles* menu in the Outliner, and enable the button shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Restriction Toggles]

As you can see in the next screenshot, a third column shows up on the right of the object names. When this button is toggled off, the object name gets grayed out, and the object gets disabled in the viewport. You just need to enable it if you want to see it in the viewport, or disable the button to its right (which looks like a camera) to disable the object in the render to match the viewport.

[image: Hidden Cube]

---

**Edit:** It seems that there are animations that were added to some of the objects by mistake. To remove them, follow the steps below.

1. Any object that has a curved arrow to the right of its name is an object that has an animation.
2. Press the folding arrow to the left of its name to expose its content.
3. Right click the animation, and run *Clear Animation Data*.

[image: Remove animations]

Comment: Hi @Mr A, thank you kindly for taking the time to answer my questions - you solved my hidden object problem. I tried using the home button to reset any accidental zooming in but the rescaling of objects post rendering issue persists. 

I gave up trying to find a simple solution and resized all the problematic objects again (mainly the Bezier curves that I'm using as wires and my resistor model objects). Unsurprisingly upon rendering the same issue occurred again and after closing the render window the objects that I'd 'fixed' had reverted again to a distorted scale

Comment: Looking back at your screenshot, it seems that you have animations on them which will overwrite your edits (unless you key them). I will add a screenshot showing how to remove them.